# query in writing while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I was trying to write code for the following query. I wanted to write the code to estimate average of first 10 integers but the code runs even if I type number 11. shouldn't it stop if i take anything above 10

follwing is my code

## take 10 integers from keyboard using loop and print their average value on the screen

```
sum = 0

i = 10

while i>0:
num = int(input("Enter an integer"))
sum = sum+num
print("the average value is:", sum/10.0)
i = i-1
```

Comment: ‘Estimate’ the average?  I see a calculation,  not an estimate.  Additionally (more on point), where is the test to determine if the integer is greater than 10; as expected by the question?  As it stands, any integer (within reason) can be entered and the code will average the 10 integers.  (Once the code is intended properly)

Comment: Your code is invalid (indentation issues). Unless you fix that then we can't be sure what you're doing wrong. In particular, is *i = i - 1* inside or outside the loop?

Comment: The while condition is `while i>0`, which does not depend on the user input at all.  Why were you expecting the loop to stop?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you're using a while loop to take 10 integers from the keyboard and calculate their average. However, the loop will continue running even if the user enters a number greater than 10. To fix this, you can add a condition inside the loop to break out of it if the user enters a number greater than 10

**code:**

```
sum = 0
i = 10

while i > 0:
    num = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    if num > 10:
        print("Number entered is greater than 10. Exiting the loop.")
        break
    sum = sum + num
    i = i - 1

if i == 0:
    print("The average value is:", sum / 10.0)
```

Comment: Two tips if I may: 1) Don’t use `sum`, it’s shadowing the builtin function.  2) Try the `+=` or `-=` operators.  For example: `i -= 1` or `sum_ += num`.  Alternatively, dump off the `while` and index counting for the `range` function, since you already know the number of loops required. For example: `for _ in range(10):`.

Comment: Several of your answers, this one included, appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: While you can't see deleted answers, someone else posted almost exactly the same answer from (presumably) ChatGPT right after or before yours.  They then probably realized that the answers look the same, and they deleted theirs.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues. m